# Newbie learning | Why dont this random.shuffle work?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

```
import random

##Why not working :(
lista = []
random_values = "Ko","Bil","Tv"
lista.append(random_values)
random.shuffle(lista)
print(lista)
```

I dont understand why this wont work...The shuffle wont shuffle the list.

Comment: Your `lista` has length 1 since it contains a single tuple of length 3. `append` doesn't work how you think it works. The problem has nothing to do with `shuffle`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
lista.extend(random_values)
```

instead. `append` just appends the tuple `("Ko", "Bil", "Tv")` to the list. It does **not** append each element of the tuple to the list.

Then, you are left with a singleton list which is unaffected by any shuffling.

Note that

```
[("Ko", "Bil", "Tv")] != ["Ko", "Bil", "Tv"]
```

where the first list contains only a single element, but the second one contains three (and can thus be meaningfully shuffled).

Comment: Thank you! I did do the .extend and it worked perfectly. I still don't quite understand the language to the full extent- my first time learning to code. Tuples seem a bit confusing. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

After

```
lista = []
random_values = "Ko","Bil","Tv"
lista.append(random_values)
```

`lista` has single element which is 3-tuple, you might do

```
random_values = "Ko","Bil","Tv"
lista = list(random_values)
```

instead